# Can I get a chargeback from Visa or MasterCard if a product I bought did not match the description?

Tags: credit-card, purchase, consumer-protection

If I buy something from a retailer and later on, when I go pick up the product, I find out that it was not the same product agreed on and they refuse to give me a refund (even through they legally have to do so), can I contact Visa, Mastercard or my bank to get a chargeback on that product?

If not, in what circumstances will they do a chargeback? Is it only if the transaction is disputed?

Comment: Is this a rhetorical question or something like this happened to you?

Comment: sort of. But I think it's useful to know my rights also.

Answer (score 6):

Dispute the charge. Receiving the wrong product is grounds for dispute.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to first try and get the seller to refund.  (Get the name of the person you talked to and a date and time).

Then you can contact the bank the card was issued through and dispute the charge.  I would make sure that you retain any proof that you purchased one item and received something other than what you purchased.  The seller does have recourse if they did fulfill their side of the transaction but if they are a legitimate merchant and actually sent you the wrong product most will not bother.

Answer (score 0):

Visa, Mastercard have very strong consumer protection. I have been wondering about this question for a while but never got around to asking it here: What happens if a retailer knowingly defrauds me?

My guess is the first party to ask for help is Visa, Mastercard: a retailer knowingly defrauding you is unlikely to refund you any money.

However, slip-ups do happen. If this is a retailer of good repute, they will not only refund you the money but send you a gift card too!

Please do followup this post with what helped you in the end, but my guess is, your first (and last) line of defense would be Visa, Mastercard. Anything that would go through the bank would take such a lot of time and effort, that you would be better off writing it off.

Comment: The consumer, as cardholder, doesn't have any business relationship with Visa or Mastercard.  You aren't their customer and they won't help you.  They might make a record of the number of complaints against a particular merchant or a particular card issuer (often but not always a bank) and eventually ban them for breaking the agreement Visa/Mastercard has with that merchant or that issuer.  Your card issuer is the one you contact to start a chargeback.